# Exclude word and quotes from regexp

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

I have the following phrases:

1. Mr "Smith"
2. MrS "Smith"

I need to retrieve only `Smith` from this phrases. I tried thousands of variants. I stoped on
`(?!Mr|MrS)([^"]+)`.
Help, please.

Comment: Do you need to match only letters? How can your input string change? Which language/regex flavour are you using?

Comment: I use `substring` function of postgres. Letters, digits and spaces. I use this function as `substring(field_name, 'regexp')`

Comment: What about `(?!Mr|MrS)(?<=^|")([^\n"]+)`? The part `(?<=^|")` says that the name must be preceded by a `"` or by the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `(?!Mr|MrS)([^"]+)` asserts from the current position that what is directly to the right is not Mr or MrS and then captures 1+ occurrences of any char except `"`

So it will not start the match at `Mr`  but it will at `r`  because at the position before the `r` the lookahead assertion it true.

---

Instead of using a lookaround, you could match either Mr or MrS and capture what is in between double quotes.

```
\mMrS? "([^"]+)"
```

- `\m` A word boundary
- `MrS?` Match `Mr` with an optional `S`
- `"` Match a space and `"`
- `([^"]+)` capture in group 1 what is between the `"`
- `"` Match  `"`

See a [postgresql demo](https://rextester.com/JUMFCG79100)

For example

```
select REGEXP_MATCHES('Mr "Smith"', '\mMrS? "([^"]+)"');
select REGEXP_MATCHES('MrS "Smith"', '\mMrS? "([^"]+)"');
```

Output

```
    regexp_matches
1   Smith

    regexp_matches
1   Smith
```

Comment: Thank you. Actualy I'm not good in regexps. Is it possible to check Mr or Mrs in one regexp? Maybe via `|` operator or something?

Comment: @СтаниславЛистратенко It already checks for either of them using `MrS?` Of course you could use `(?:Mr|MrS) "([^"]+)"` but that would be unnecessary. Although, if you want to check for more alternations, you could use `(?:MrS?|Sir) "([^"]+)"` See https://regex101.com/r/1vGsbr/1